# IDEA 12 disable strange XML highlight

Tags: intellij-idea

This is how my pom.xml file looks in IDEA 12.

I hate how the app highlights the opening and closing `<` `>` signs.

How can I disable it?!

[IDEA 12 XML Highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeOTc.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to **Settings (Preferences) | Editor | Colors&Fonts | XML**. On the right side choose *Tag* and select *Background* checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get rid of the grey background for XML, HTML and related formats, go to **Settings (Preferences) | Editor | Colors&Fonts | Language Defaults** and uncheck **Background** for **Markup Tag**.

I think the default setting was intended to highlight the difference between tags and content, but indeed, it's not very pleasant looking.